# Finding the balance between the tensile strength of a wheel spoke, and the number of spokes required to support the wheel.

Tags: geometry, physics

This [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/7374/1259) and [response](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/7383/1259) on bicycles.se has me wondering how to find the answer mathematically.

Finding the balance between the tensile strength of a wheel spoke, and the number of spokes required to support the wheel is the point. I have no idea where to start. This is not really homework, just interesting to me personally.

Can you help?

Comment: It sounds more of a physics question to me, actually.

Comment: Feel free to migrate to physics if necessary. I'm not sure where the best place for this question is, and I didn't want to post in multiple places.